# Python:Converting specific elements in 2D array from string to integer permanently

Tags: python, list

I want to convert the 2nd Value in each list to integers, to then be increased by 1. This is an abstraction of a different code I am programming, but stuck on how to do it efficiently and keep getting errors. This will hopefully lead to 4 becoming 5, 16 to 17, and 7 to 8.

```
listp=[["3","4"],
    ["7","16"],
    ["3","7"]]


listp = list(map(int, listp[x][1]))

length = len(listp)-1
i=0
for i in range(0, length):
    num=listp[i]
    num=num+1
    listp[i]=num
    i=i+1
print (listp)
```

Comment: What do you think `x` is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem of your code is mainly the wrong usage of `map()`function. The 1st argument must be a function to apply on each item of the iterator given as the 2nd argument. The returned value of this function is the map item.
So, if you really want to use `map()`, I suggest you:

- to use `map()` to convert the 2nd items of each sublist into an integer
- and to use also `map()` to increment the converted 2nd item.

Here is my suggested one-line stylish solution using `map()`, short and easily readable:

```
listp=[["3","4"], ["7","16"], ["3","7"]]

listp = list(map(lambda x:[x[0],int(x[1])+1], listp))

print(listp)
# [['3', 5], ['7', 17], ['3', 8]]
```

However my preferred solution is to use list comprehesion, which I found easier to read and understand, as follows:

```
listp=[["3","4"], ["7","16"], ["3","7"]]

listp = [[x[0], int(x[1])+1] for x in listp]

print(listp)
# [['3', 5], ['7', 17], ['3', 8]]
```

And now let's try to start from your original code. After following updates, it also works:

```
listp=[["3","4"], ["7","16"], ["3","7"]]

length = len(listp)
for i in range(0, length):
    listp[i][1] = int(listp[i][1])
    num=listp[i][1]
    num=num+1
    listp[i][1]=num

print(listp)
# [['3', 5], ['7', 17], ['3', 8]]
```

Even if the `for`loop could be simplified like this:

```
listp=[["3","4"], ["7","16"], ["3","7"]]

for i in range(len(listp)):
    listp[i][1] = int(listp[i][1]) + 1

print(listp)
# [['3', 5], ['7', 17], ['3', 8]]
```

Choose the best way for you !

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> listp = [['3', '4'], ['7', '16'], ['3', '7']]
>>> f = lambda row: [row[0], int(row[1])+1]
>>> [f(row) for row in listp]
[['3', 5], ['7', 17], ['3', 8]]
>>>
```

Comment: This code snippet won't be very helpful to other people with this problem without at least a little explanation of what you're doing and why they might choose his approach over the accepted answer